# Added duplicate td for existing table using jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a `td` for existing table using `jQuery`. But it's adding duplicate. How to validate exactly to add the `td`.

**I have tried below code:**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>head1</th>
    <th>head2</th>
    <th>head3</th>
    <th>head4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td class="test test2">a1</td>
            <td>a2</td>
            <td>a3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="test">c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery code**

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

       for(i=0;i<2;i++){
         var row = '<td style="background: red">b_'+ i +'</td>';    
                $('[class="test"]').before(row);
       }

})
        </script>
```

I want to add a `td` where exactly match the **class="test"** is, but it's adding both **class="test test2"** and class="test".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested and working

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       for(i=0;i<2;i++){
         var row = '<td style="background: red">b_'+ i +'</td>';    
                $('.test').before(row);
       }

})
```

other solution

```
 $(document).ready(function() { var i=1;
    $(".test").each(function() { 
   if(i!=1) {
    var row = '<td style="background: red">b_'+ i +'</td>';    
                    $(this).before(row);
    }
                    i=i+1;
})  });
```

Comment: have you tried above code. it's adding duplicates yar please run your system above code you will know what happening. above code also adding duplicate. Please provide possible solution.

Comment: every `tr` add one `td` only not both. here adding 2 `td`'s for all `tr` i.e row.

Comment: added another solution kindly try and feedback

Comment: @Magento007 added the second solution and it is working tested by mysqlef.

Comment: but not for first row.  for adding first row is not require

Comment: added the condition for first..

Comment: @UaisarSatti actually I have nested loop. From my side it's not working could you please update the answer plz. my code like `for( j = 0; j<product_count.lenth; ++j){ $(".test").each(function() { // logic }); }`.

Comment: either you have to put different class for every product so then your logic can work.. `for( j = 0; j<product_count.lenth; ++j){ $(".test"+j).each(function() { // logic }); }`

Comment: @uaisarsatti actually `.test` is a class name and file's also not editable. I am dynamically adding `td` using `jQuery`. you can see my store to add two products and navigate to checkout page you will know the idea. http://v2229882.qk37a9gjz3bm.demo47.volusion.com/

Comment: simple test class  each will work for you.. this will put one td before where the class exist.